# Outlier/anomaly detection for dependent variable in predictive model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, outliers, anomaly-detection

**Context:** We have data on numbers of infection cases reported by thousands of hospitals across the country. We know that many of these hospitals are underreporting incidents, and we'd like to flag those hospitals which we suspect may be underreporting for closer inspection/investigation.

**Data:** Counts of infection cases for thousands of hospitals (each data point is a single hospital), and some hospital attributes (staff size, average income of neighborhood, etc.). There is no labelling of underreporting hospitals to train a model off of.

**Desired output:** Some kind of quantification of the likelihood that a given hospital is underreporting, for use in a kind of 'underreporting index'.

**Attempted solution:** We had thought to fit the data to a Poisson/Negative Binomial GLM, and use each point's position on the Poisson/NegBi probability mass function (the parameters of which are estimated from the GLM) as a measure of the likelihood that the hospital is underreporting. (We would only look at one side of the distribution, since we're interested in underreporting).

The results of this aren't terrible but the fit is far from perfect (see plot):

[image: basic model]

Here, I built a NegBi GLM using just one explanatory variable – the number of civilians that fall within the hospital's zone of consideration (x-axis). The reported number of infections is on the y-axis. Both shown in ln scale. Each point is a hospital, the blue line is the expectation from the GLM, red lines are the 5th and 95th percentiles (roughly obviously because we're talking about a discrete distribution) of the corresponding NegBi distribution. Inclusion of other variables don't actually seem to improve the fit by much.

Obviously the deficiencies in the fit (whether due to the high number of outliers or for other reasons) compromise the usability of this method. As such, I was wondering whether there were other methods we should consider to achieve the above-mentioned objective. I haven't found any applicable solutions from browsing other related SE questions.